# How to get IEEE 802.11a Wireless Mode on Linux (including Ubuntu)?

Tags: networking, wireless

So basically I have been trying to switch to Linux for the past few months because I'm getting increasingly sick of Microsoft's bullsh*t, unfortunately my wireless card seems to only reliably work with the 'Wireless Mode' set to IEEE 802.11a, otherwise it starts to fail in every way imaginable. This setting was hard for me to find in Windows 10, but seems to be even more elusive on Linux.

Any help is appreciated, my dad keeps putting off getting an ethernet cable through the wall though I've literally been asking for half a year.

[image: screenshot of the setting in Windows 10]

when putting this in the terminal: `lspci - nn | grep Network`
I get:

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
```

Comment: I don't see a reason to set a similar option on Linux and I doubt there is one.

Comment: @Pilot6 so people can use their wireless cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I am assuming you are using Ubuntu, with that in mind, here are some of the things others have tried that worked for that specific model (10ec:8812 rev 01):

- Switching antennas used on the wireless card. For some reason, there is a case where this worked.
- Using latest Ubuntu version (19.04 as of this post)
- Updating the BIOS in the laptop/computer. Since you are also not mentioning this, I will recommend checking if a BIOS update is pending that could fix this. I know of several cases where, at the end, the issue was the lack of a BIOS update that targeted the network device.
- Installing the latest GIT drivers for Realtek (Careful with this one since I can't test it myself). The way to install this would be the following after you have updated all packages:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt install linux-headers-5.0.0-15-generic  # Just in case they are needed
  git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
  cd rtlwifi_new 
  make
  sudo make install
  sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
  ```

Comment: It doesn't seem that the wireless adapter doesn't work for OP. (S)he is looking for 802.11a option if I am correct.

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6 This would allow the OP to use the card in 802.11a and any other 802.11 since the OP mentions the 802.11a case because the others have issues. As long as the correct drivers are installed and the kernel supports the card 100% then it will work. And since 4.18 (more or less) it got full support. Hence why I ask for the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the help,
I will install ubuntu in the morning, i'll also install those GIT drivers.
I doubt its an outdated BIOS issue though as it works fine on Windows.

When I first got this problem on Windows it was set to 'Auto' rather than 802.11a etc. After I follow your steps should it 'just work' or are there any settings/terminal commands required?

Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: You would need to provide feedback on that, after you try all points. With that as base we can continue helping you in finding a solution.